# Uvicorn server is not working in terminal in windows

Tags: python, fastapi

```
(fastapi) E:\Python Practice\FastAPI\fastapi\fastapi>uvicorn main:app --reload 
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['E:\\Python Practice\\FastAPI\\fastapi\\fastapi']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
INFO:     Started reloader process [7344] using statreload
WARNING:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".
```

Comment: It shows me an error below that "The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows."

Comment: It can't find your ASGI app. The `--reload` message is just a warning that is not related to your issue. "Could not import module `main`" seems to indicate that you do not have a `main.py` or similar where the `app` is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried installing only uvicorn but not the standard version.

Standard version is for MacOS and Windows users should prefer installing uvicorn.